# Are Christian images of Jesus sacrilege?

Tags: christianity, prophet-isa, image

If Islam prohibits depicting prophets, and consider Jesus a prophet (although not the biggest one), are all these images of Jesus in Christian hands some kind of sacrilege?

Comment: I am not sure I get the question. Can somebody rephrase or explain the question?

Answer (score 1):

The use of images, statues, or any visual representation of prophets or religious figures, including Jesus (peace be upon him), is generally discouraged or prohibited. This is because Islam emphasizes the unity and oneness of God, and views the creation of images as potentially leading to idolatry or the worship of created objects.

Therefore, while Islamic tradition recognizes and respects the figure of Jesus as a prophet and messenger of God, Muslims do not typically use images or representations of him for worship or religious purposes.

As for the question of whether Christian images of Jesus are considered sacrilege in Islam, this would depend on the context and purpose of the images. If the images are being used for worship or veneration of Jesus as a divine figure, then from an Islamic perspective, this would be considered sacrilegious or even shirk (associating partners with God).

However, if the images are being used in a non-religious context, such as for artistic or educational purposes, and are not being venerated or worshipped, then they may not be considered sacrilegious in Islam.

It's important to note that Islamic teachings emphasize respect for the beliefs and practices of others, and condemn any form of disrespect, insult, or intolerance towards individuals or communities based on their religious beliefs.
To find out more about this please follow the link:
https://www.islamiqate.com/274/how-do-muslims-refer-to-jesus-christ

Answer (score -3):

> روى أحمد وأبو داود عن أبي هريرة ، عن النبي صَلَّى اللَّهُ عَلَيْهِ
>   وَسَلَّمَ قال: “لَيْسَ بَيْني وَبَيْنَ عيسى نَبِيٌّ وإنَّهُ نازِلٌ
>   فَإذا رَأَيْتُموهُ فاعْرِفوهُ: رَجُلٌ مَرْبوعٌ إلى الحُمْرَةِ
>   والبَياضِ، يَنزِلُ بَيْنَ مُمَصَّرَتَينِ، كَأنَّ رَأسَهُ يَقْطُرُ وإنْ
>   لَم يَصُبْهُ بَلَلٌ، فَيُقاتِلُ النّاسَ عَلى الإسْلامِ، فَيَدُقُّ
>   الصَّليبَ، وَيَقْتُلُ الخِنْزيرَ، وَيَضَعُ الجِزْيَةَ، ويُهْلِكُ
>   اللَّهُ في زَمانِهِ المِلَلَ كُلَّها إلاّ الإسْلامَ، وَيُهْلِكَ
>   المَسيحَ الدَّجَّالَ ، فَيَمْكُثُ في الأرْضِ أرْبَعينَ سَنَةً ثُمَّ
>   يُتَوَفَّى فَيُصَلّي عَلَيهِ المُسْلِمونَ”
>
> Translation: Ahmad and Abu-Dawood narrated from Abi-Horaira that the
>   Prophet (blessing and peace be upon him) said: "There is no prophet
>   between me and Eisa and he (Eisa) will descend so when you (people)
>   see it then know him: (He is) a man (who is) average to reddish and
>   light (skin) color. He will descend in two yellow clothes. His head
>   looks like as if it drips even when it is not wet. So he will fight
>   people for Islam, so he will break crosses, kill pigs and stop the
>   Jezyah (money that non-Muslims pay) and Allah in his (Eisa's) time
>   will make all religions and sect perish except Islam, and He will make
>   Al-Maseeh Al-Daggaal (a man who will be able to do paranormals and
>   will claim he is god) perish, and he (Eisa) will stay in the earth for
>   fourty years then he will die and Muslims will pray (Janaza prayer)
>   upon him"

So, in this hadith Jesus is depicted as average reddish and light color. I think it is not wrong for Christians to depict Jesus Christ, but with the reference from the Ten Commandments imagery may still be prohibited.

Comment: that is hadith, not quran. and it seems, hadith contradicts about color of jesus. lets [ask the question](http://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/12106/color-of-jesus-hadith-contradicts) and see what others opine.