# What color is Jesus, and is there a Hadith contradiction?

Tags: hadith-interpretation, prophet-isa

In some hadith, Jesus is said to be of red or reddish-white. eg:

> Narrated Ibn `Abbas:
>   The Prophet (ﷺ) said, "I saw Moses, Jesus and Abraham (on the night of my Ascension to the heavens). Jesus was of **red complexion**, curly hair and a broad chest [ [ref](http://sunnah.com/bukhari/60/109) ]

Also see Jesus was **[reddish-white](http://sunnah.com/bukhari/92/75)**.
Yet another hadith says:

> Narrated Salim from his father:
>   No, By Allah, the Prophet (ﷺ) **did not tell** that Jesus was of red complexion but said, "While I was asleep circumambulating the Ka`ba (in my dream), suddenly I saw a man of **brown complexion**. He was the son of Mary. [[ref](http://sunnah.com/bukhari/60/111)]

Only Allah knows the truth, but my question is: why two sahih hadiths contradict each other or, why two contradicting hadith are graded as sahih?

Comment: you will get your answer here: http://www.rationalskepticism.org/islam/what-did-jesus-look-like-according-to-muhammad-t16563.html specially the reply number 7 by assi

Comment: also look http://www.islamicboard.com/clarifications-about-islam/134306855-isa-complexion.html

Comment: @Zia Ul Rehman, I checked the Answer #7 you mentioned and I do not agree with it.

Comment: Please note that all 3 narratives you refer to use the same word رَجُلٌ أَحْمَرُ. It is the translator who translated it differently in each occurrence.

Answer (score 2):

There is **no contradiction** in the original Arabic text of Hadiths.

I checked the translation, it translates this part (A man "Aadam") as (a man of brown complexion), and that is because they translate the word, but it does not work that way, **in Arabic you need to understand the context** so if you read the word Adam in Moajam (Arabic dictionary), you see it has different meanings one of them is dark complexion, but another meaning is complexion, and if you read the Arabic explication for the group of Hadiths about Jesus, it's clear that Jesus had white reddish complexion. ِِ

So to understand this check the other Hadith, it will be easier to understand when you read the complete context:

> رَجُلاً آدَمَ كَأَحْسَنِ مَا تَرَى مِنْ أُدْمِ الرِّجَالِ

which is translated to :

> Man with complexion which is the best you may see for men complexion.

Now try to join both Hadiths, it's not complicated, he has white reddish complexion as the best you may see for a man.

That, and Allah knows best.

Comment: But how do you explain the apparent contradiction between the first hadith in which the prophet is clearly attributed as saying "عِيسَى فَأَحْمَرُ جَعْدٌ عَرِيضُ الصَّدْرِ" and the second which claims "لاَ وَاللَّهِ مَا قَالَ النَّبِيُّ صلى الله عليه وسلم لِعِيسَى أَحْمَرُ"?

Comment: This obvious (and normal) that both Hadiths are Sahih, Ibn Omar did not hear the Hadith which Ibn Abbas narrated (companions were not all arround the prophet (PBUH)) all time.

Answer (score 1):

These two narrations both having Sahih chains means they authentically trace back to Ibn Umar (the father of Salim) and Ibn Abbas (RA) respectively.

In fact, the hadith of Ibn Umar confirms in some ways the authenticity of the hadith of Ibn Abbas (RA) since he says:

> No, By Allah, the Prophet (ﷺ) did not tell that Jesus was of red complexion

What this statement indicates is that he heard someone saying Jesus (AS) was of a red complexion. And that someone probably heard it from Ibn Abbas. So, this hadith confirms or corroborates somewhat that the other narration exists.

Now, why did the two companions disagree?

This is probably because of a confusion of Ibn Umar (RA). These are the two narrations:

> Ibn Abbas (RA): The Prophet (ﷺ) said, "**I saw Moses, Jesus and Abraham (on the night of my Ascension to the heavens). Jesus was of red complexion, curly hair and a broad chest.** Moses was of brown complexion, straight hair and tall stature as if he was from the people of Az-Zutt."
>
> Ibn Umar (RA): The Prophet (ﷺ) said, "**While I was asleep circumambulating the Ka'ba (in my dream), suddenly I saw a man of brown complexion and lank hair walking between two men**, and water was dropping from his head. I asked, 'Who is this?' The people said, 'He is the son of Mary.' Then I looked behind and I saw a red-complexioned, fat, curly-haired man, blind in the right eye which looked like a bulging out grape. I asked, 'Who is this?' They replied, 'He is Ad-Dajjal.' The one who resembled to him among the people, was Ibn Qatar." (Az-Zuhri said, "He (i.e. Ibn Qatan) was a man from the tribe Khuza`a who died in the pre-lslamic period.")

These are clearly two different times the Prophet (SAW) described Isa (AS). The one using the phrase "reddish" is while the Prophet (SAW) is describing the Isra. The one using the term "brown" is while the Prophet (SAW) describes a dream he had of Isa (AS).

It is most likely that the Prophet (SAW) described Isa (AS) in both ways in these two different occasions. Perhaps for whatever reason, the lighting or circumstances made Isa (AS) appear lighter in the Isra than in the dream. Or perhaps (since the colors are close enough anyway), the Prophet (SAW) used them interchangeably.

Ibn Umar (RA) was probably not present when the first narration occurred while Ibn Abbas (RA) was present. So, when Ibn Umar heard people describe Isa (AS) as "reddish" according to Ibn Abbas (RA)'s narration, he incorrectly assumed they were misquoting and messing up the second narration.

That is why he "corrected" them and quoted the second narration.

Answer (score 0):

The Ancient Israelites were people of color, Isa was probably light brown in color with chiseled features, such as a aquiline nose and a youthful look.

Moses is described as being dark-skinned. https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=4T4J55Fu5jo&t=1411s

Answer (score -1):

The prophet Muhammed ( sallallahio alayhi wa salami) said in sahib Muslim Hadith that he saw Prophet Isa ( pbuh) going around around the kabah leaning on two Angels and his skin was a beautiful brown color,the color red is destincly different from brown,you have to be careful of what you read during these times the enemies of Islam have access to the various Hadith,whereby printing their own interpretation,so that they can create confusion .

Comment: Welcome to Islam SE. Answers should be elaborate and focused on addressing the question. Claims should be supported by evidence. Please visit our [tour] in the [help], and refer to [answer].

Answer (score -1):

1. Jesus of Israel = Jesus in comparison with Moses,

It's said that Jesus is red complexioned (some hadith says just reddish like a man come out a bathroom). It is also said Jesus have curly hair.

2. Jesus of Muslim Ummah = In comparison with Dajjal,

It is said that Jesus who will descend will be brown colored (the best men you can see in brown colour). This Jesus will be having a long straight hair, some hadith says that it will be feel like water dribbling in that lank hair.

The hadiths are not confusing and the words of Prophet Muhammad (saw) are exactly true in the sense there are two Jesus.

1. Jesus of Israel whom died at the age of 120 in Kashmir, India after surviving the cruxifixion.
2. Jesus promised to be the Umatti of Prophet Muhammad (saw), none other than Syeddina Ghazi Imam Mirza Ghulam Ahmad of Qadian.

Peace be upon all the prophets.

Answer (score -1):

Isa (as) described in the Isra is the one who is a 'rasool' to Bani Israel. According to the Quran he died. 'mutawaffika'. The other complexion of Brownish color and lank hair is that of Isa who is to fight Dajjal'. He will come in the latter days. The example is similar to the second coming of Elijah in Bible, who was supposed to come before Jesus. Jesus himself explained this. He said that second coming of Elijah was fulfilled in the coming of John, the Baptist.

Answer (score -2):

It is interesting that the Holy Prophetsaw made it clear that the latter day messiah would be someone completely different. Hesaw states in regards to the description of the messiahas sent to Bani Israel:

حَدَّثَنَا مُحَمَّدُ بْنُ كَثِيرٍ، أَخْبَرَنَا إِسْرَائِيلُ، أَخْبَرَنَا عُثْمَانُ بْنُ الْمُغِيرَةِ، عَنْ مُجَاهِدٍ، عَنِ ابْنِ عَبَّاسٍ ـ رضى الله عنهما ـ قَالَ قَالَ النَّبِيُّ صلى الله عليه وسلم ‏ “‏ رَأَيْتُ عِيسَى وَمُوسَى وَإِبْرَاهِيمَ، فَأَمَّا عِيسَى فَأَحْمَرُ جَعْدٌ عَرِيضُ الصَّدْرِ، وَأَمَّا مُوسَى فَآدَمُ جَسِيمٌ سَبْطٌ كَأَنَّهُ مِنْ رِجَالِ الزُّطِّ ‏”‏‏.‏

Narrated Ibn `Abbas: The Prophet (ﷺ) said, “I saw Moses, Jesus and Abraham (on the night of my Ascension to the heavens). Jesus was of red complexion, curly hair and a broad chest. Moses was of brown complexion, straight hair and tall stature as if he was from the people of Az-Zutt.” (Bukhari Volume 4, book 55, Hadith 648)

Hesaw states in regards to the Messiah of the end times who was to be from our ummah:

حَدَّثَنَا إِبْرَاهِيمُ بْنُ الْمُنْذِرِ، حَدَّثَنَا أَبُو ضَمْرَةَ، حَدَّثَنَا مُوسَى، عَنْ نَافِعٍ، قَالَ عَبْدُ اللَّهِ ذَكَرَ النَّبِيُّ صلى الله عليه وسلم يَوْمًا بَيْنَ ظَهْرَىِ النَّاسِ الْمَسِيحَ الدَّجَّالَ، فَقَالَ ‏”‏ إِنَّ اللَّهَ لَيْسَ بِأَعْوَرَ، أَلاَ إِنَّ الْمَسِيحَ الدَّجَّالَ أَعْوَرُ الْعَيْنِ الْيُمْنَى، كَأَنَّ عَيْنَهُ عِنَبَةٌ طَافِيَةٌ ‏”‏‏.‏ ‏”‏ وَأَرَانِي اللَّيْلَةَ عِنْدَ الْكَعْبَةِ فِي الْمَنَامِ، فَإِذَا رَجُلٌ آدَمُ كَأَحْسَنِ مَا يُرَى مِنْ أُدْمِ الرِّجَالِ، تَضْرِبُ لِمَّتُهُ بَيْنَ مَنْكِبَيْهِ، رَجِلُ الشَّعَرِ، يَقْطُرُ رَأْسُهُ مَاءً، وَاضِعًا يَدَيْهِ عَلَى مَنْكِبَىْ رَجُلَيْنِ وَهْوَ يَطُوفُ بِالْبَيْتِ‏.‏ فَقُلْتُ مَنْ هَذَا فَقَالُوا هَذَا الْمَسِيحُ ابْنُ مَرْيَمَ‏.‏ ثُمَّ رَأَيْتُ رَجُلاً وَرَاءَهُ جَعْدًا قَطَطًا أَعْوَرَ عَيْنِ الْيُمْنَى كَأَشْبَهِ مَنْ رَأَيْتُ بِابْنِ قَطَنٍ، وَاضِعًا يَدَيْهِ عَلَى مَنْكِبَىْ رَجُلٍ، يَطُوفُ بِالْبَيْتِ، فَقُلْتُ مَنْ هَذَا قَالُوا الْمَسِيحُ الدَّجَّالُ ‏”‏‏.‏ تَابَعَهُ عُبَيْدُ اللَّهِ عَنْ نَافِعٍ‏.‏

Narrated `Abdullah:The Prophet (ﷺ) mentioned the Masih Ad-Dajjal in front of the people saying, Allah is not one-eyed while Masih Ad-Dajjal is blind in the right eye and his eye looks like a bulging out grape. While sleeping near the Ka`ba last night, I saw in my dream a man of brown color the best one can see amongst brown color and his hair was long that it fell between his shoulders. His hair was lank and water was dribbling from his head and he was placing his hands on the shoulders of two men while circumambulating the Ka`ba. I asked, ‘Who is this?’ They replied, ‘This is Jesus, son of Mary.’ Behind him I saw a man who had very curly hair and was blind in the right eye, resembling Ibn Qatan (i.e. an infidel) in appearance. He was placing his hands on the shoulders of a person while performing Tawaf around the Ka`ba. I asked, ‘Who is this? ‘They replied, ‘The Masih, Ad-Dajjal.’ (sahih Bukhari Volume 4, book 55, Hadith #649)

There have been attempts to state that the Prophetsaw did not mention Isaas being of reddish complexion. This is a total confusion which is not true at all. All the descriptions of the Messiah sent to Bani Israel always mentions reddish complexion, while the latter always mentions brown complexion. The Prophet Muhammadsaw has clearly showed a distinction between the Messiahs.

Another beautiful point to notice is that all Muslims know that the one to revive Islam would be the same Messiah who was prophesied about. We all know that Isaas was of Bani Israel, however, Muhammadsaw made it clear that the one to revive Islam would be of the Persian Lineage, as Ahmadas was:

حَدَّثَنِي عَبْدُ الْعَزِيزِ بْنُ عَبْدِ اللَّهِ، قَالَ حَدَّثَنِي سُلَيْمَانُ بْنُ بِلاَلٍ، عَنْ ثَوْرٍ، عَنْ أَبِي الْغَيْثِ، عَنْ أَبِي هُرَيْرَةَ، رضى الله عنه قَالَ كُنَّا جُلُوسًا عِنْدَ النَّبِيِّ صلى الله عليه وسلم فَأُنْزِلَتْ عَلَيْهِ سُورَةُ الْجُمُعَةِ ‏{‏وَآخَرِينَ مِنْهُمْ لَمَّا يَلْحَقُوا بِهِمْ‏}‏ قَالَ قُلْتُ مَنْ هُمْ يَا رَسُولَ اللَّهِ فَلَمْ يُرَاجِعْهُ حَتَّى سَأَلَ ثَلاَثًا، وَفِينَا سَلْمَانُ الْفَارِسِيُّ، وَضَعَ رَسُولُ اللَّهِ صلى الله عليه وسلم يَدَهُ عَلَى سَلْمَانَ ثُمَّ قَالَ ‏”‏ لَوْ كَانَ الإِيمَانُ عِنْدَ الثُّرَيَّا لَنَالَهُ رِجَالٌ ـ أَوْ رَجُلٌ ـ مِنْ هَؤُلاَءِ ‏”‏‏.‏

Narrated Abu Huraira: While we were sitting with the Prophet (ﷺ) Surat Al-Jumu’a was revealed to him, and when the Verse, “And He (Allah) has sent him (Muhammad) also to other (Muslims)…..’ (62.3) was recited by the Prophet, I said, “Who are they, O Allah’s Messenger (ﷺ)?” The Prophet (ﷺ) did not reply till I repeated my question thrice. At that time, Salman Al-Farisi was with us. So Allah’s Messenger (ﷺ) put his hand on Salman, saying, “If Faith were at (the place of) Ath-Thuraiya (pleiades, the highest star), even then a man from these people (i.e. Salman’s folk) would attain it.” (Bukhari, Volume 6, Book 60, Hadith #4897)

Another important point is that when Muhammadsaw mentions the Messiahas of the past, hesaw mentions him being in the company of the dead, who include Mosesas and Abrahamas, and when hesaw mentions the latter day messiahas, hesaw mentions its company with the living dajjal rather than the dead. It is also important to note that Imam Bukhari narrated these traditions right after each other which further proves his knowledge on the fact that it would be two different Messiahs. Some have tried to quote:

حَدَّثَنَا هُدْبَةُ بْنُ خَالِدٍ، حَدَّثَنَا هَمَّامُ بْنُ يَحْيَى، عَنْ قَتَادَةَ، عَنْ عَبْدِ الرَّحْمَنِ بْنِ آدَمَ، عَنْ أَبِي هُرَيْرَةَ، أَنَّ النَّبِيَّ صلى الله عليه وسلم قَالَ ‏ “‏ لَيْسَ بَيْنِي وَبَيْنَهُ نَبِيٌّ – يَعْنِي عِيسَى – وَإِنَّهُ نَازِلٌ فَإِذَا رَأَيْتُمُوهُ فَاعْرِفُوهُ رَجُلٌ مَرْبُوعٌ إِلَى الْحُمْرَةِ وَالْبَيَاضِ بَيْنَ مُمَصَّرَتَيْنِ كَأَنَّ رَأْسَهُ يَقْطُرُ وَإِنْ لَمْ يُصِبْهُ بَلَلٌ فَيُقَاتِلُ النَّاسَ عَلَى الإِسْلاَمِ فَيَدُقُّ الصَّلِيبَ وَيَقْتُلُ الْخِنْزِيرَ وَيَضَعُ الْجِزْيَةَ وَيُهْلِكُ اللَّهُ فِي زَمَانِهِ الْمِلَلَ كُلَّهَا إِلاَّ الإِسْلاَمَ وَيُهْلِكُ الْمَسِيحَ الدَّجَّالَ فَيَمْكُثُ فِي الأَرْضِ أَرْبَعِينَ سَنَةً ثُمَّ يُتَوَفَّى فَيُصَلِّي عَلَيْهِ الْمُسْلِمُونَ ‏”‏ ‏.‏

Narrated Abu Hurayrah:The Prophet (ﷺ) said: There is no prophet between me and him, that is, Jesus (ﷺ). He will descent (to the earth). When you see him, recognise him: a man of medium height, reddish fair, wearing two light yellow garments, looking as if drops were falling down from his head though it will not be wet. He will fight the people for the cause of Islam. He will break the cross, kill swine, and abolish jizyah. Allah will perish all religions except Islam. He will destroy the Antichrist and will live on the earth for forty years and then he will die. The Muslims will pray over him.(Sunan Abi Dawud, Hadith #4324)

They claim that in this hadith, in regards to the latter day messiah, it mentions that he would be of reddish complexion. Firstly, such a explanation which contradicts over eleven sahih ahadith including ahadith of Bukhari and Muslim does not hold any weight. Furthermore, this narration is already corrected in Bukhari and it has been made clear that it was a mistake in narration. It is mentioned in Bukhari in regards to the latter day Messiah who was to descend:

حَدَّثَنَا أَحْمَدُ بْنُ مُحَمَّدٍ الْمَكِّيُّ، قَالَ سَمِعْتُ إِبْرَاهِيمَ بْنَ سَعْدٍ، قَالَ حَدَّثَنِي الزُّهْرِيُّ، عَنْ سَالِمٍ، عَنْ أَبِيهِ،، قَالَ لاَ وَاللَّهِ مَا قَالَ النَّبِيُّ صلى الله عليه وسلم لِعِيسَى أَحْمَرُ، وَلَكِنْ قَالَ ‏ “‏ بَيْنَمَا أَنَا نَائِمٌ أَطُوفُ بِالْكَعْبَةِ، فَإِذَا رَجُلٌ آدَمُ سَبْطُ الشَّعَرِ، يُهَادَى بَيْنَ رَجُلَيْنِ، يَنْطِفُ رَأْسُهُ مَاءً أَوْ يُهَرَاقُ رَأْسُهُ مَاءً فَقُلْتُ مَنْ هَذَا قَالُوا ابْنُ مَرْيَمَ، فَذَهَبْتُ أَلْتَفِتُ، فَإِذَا رَجُلٌ أَحْمَرُ جَسِيمٌ، جَعْدُ الرَّأْسِ، أَعْوَرُ عَيْنِهِ الْيُمْنَى، كَأَنَّ عَيْنَهُ عِنَبَةٌ طَافِيَةٌ‏.‏ قُلْتُ مَنْ هَذَا قَالُوا هَذَا الدَّجَّالُ‏.‏ وَأَقْرَبُ النَّاسِ بِهِ شَبَهًا ابْنُ قَطَنٍ ‏”‏‏.‏ قَالَ الزُّهْرِيُّ رَجُلٌ مِنْ خُزَاعَةَ هَلَكَ فِي الْجَاهِلِيَّةِ‏.‏

Narrated Salim from his father:No, By Allah, the Prophet (ﷺ) did not tell that Jesus was of red complexion but said, “While I was asleep circumambulating the Ka`ba (in my dream), suddenly I saw a man of brown complexion and lank hair walking between two men, and water was dropping from his head. I asked, ‘Who is this?’ The people said, ‘He is the son of Mary.’ Then I looked behind and I saw a red-complexioned, fat, curly-haired man, blind in the right eye which looked like a bulging out grape. I asked, ‘Who is this?’ They replied, ‘He is Ad-Dajjal.’ The one who resembled to him among the people, was Ibn Qatar.” (Az-Zuhri said, “He (i.e. Ibn Qatan) was a man from the tribe Khuza`a who died in the pre-lslamic period.”) (Sahih al Bukhari, Volume 4, Book 55, Hadith #650)

This can not refer to the description of the Messiah sent to Bani Israel of being reddish complexion since there are many narrations which are authentic that make the difference of complexions clear. However, the narration of Abu Dawud comes to question as it contradicts the authentic ahadith which describe the appearance of the Messiah of the end times. This saying makes it clear that the Prophet Muhammadsaw did not say that the latter day Messiah would be of reddish complexion, and would be of brown complexion. Furthermore, the description in the hadith of Abu Dawood is describing the latter day Messiah and describes him the same way as the other ahadith of Bukhari except the skin colour. Its possible that this was a error in narration from Abu Hurairahra as well. One cannot reject this clear narration of Hazrat Umarra who makes it clear that the latter day Messiah would be of brownish complexion. No one has the right to claim that the ahadith which use reddish complexion are in reality a error by quoting this hadith, since there are many ahadith that say reddish and many that say brown. A mistake would not be repeated over 11 times by different narrators. Every time the Messiah of Bani Israel is mentioned, hes described as reddish skin, while the Messiah of the end times is always described as brownish in the most authentic book after the Qur’an, which is Bukhari. Another important point to note is that the Holy Prophet Muhammadsaw knew how the Messiah of Bani Israel looked like, uet when it came to the visions of the Messiah who was to come in the end times, hesaw asked “Who is this”?, which shows it was to be someone else, in the likeness of Isaas.

It is clear that the description of both Messiahs is clearly different.